# Passing database results into header file in PHP-MVC

Tags: php

I'm starting a new project using the http://www.php-mvc.net framework but have never had to include database results in the header file before and not sure how to go about it. I need to pull a list of current categories and there ID's from the database and use them to populate a menu.

The header.php file is in /views/_templates. The normal way of passing database results to the view is to run the query in the relevant model, get the data in the controller, pass the data from the controller to the view, then loop over the data with a foreach loop in the view. The problem being the _template files don't have any kind of controller for them.

The best I can come up with is to use include and include a view file from the home controller, using that controller to get the results and pass them to a menu.php in the views/home folder.

/views/_templates/header.php

```
    <li class="dropdown">
        <?php include 'views/home/menu.php'; ?>
    </li>
```

/views/home/menu.php

```
foreach ($links as $link){
    <a href="<?php echo URL . $link->url; ?>"><li><?php echo $link->name; ?></li></a>
}
```

- the above code has been shortened its more for principle than a working example.

The method I have come up with works but I wanted to know if there's a more elegant way of doing things?

Comment: Normally you would do this with the concept of a "component" which is generally speaking a way to tie together a controller and view during the lifecyle of a single request or a "subrequest" if you will. Seems like this concept is missing within the framework you have chosen.

Comment: I think my only other option that I can see is it pull the information using the main controller class, store the array into a session and then iterate over the array in the header file, can you see any possible problems with this?

Comment: No need to store in session you could use a Twig global so its available in all templates and you could make sure that your base controller runs a preExceute to pull all the data together and then add that global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented:

> No need to store in session you could use a Twig global so its available in all templates and you could make sure that your base controller runs a preExceute to pull all the data together and then add that global.

That might look something like this:

```
abstract class MyBaseController extends Controller
{
  private $view = null;

  private prepareView()
  {
      $twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(PATH_VIEWS);
      return new Twig_Environment($twig_loader);
  }

  public function getView()
  {
     if ($this->view === null) {
        $this->view = $this->prepareView();
     }

     return $this->view;
  }

  protected function preRender()
  {
     // whatever logic you need to prepare the menu data as $links
     $this->getView()->addGlobal('links', $links);
  }

  public function render($view, $data_array = array())
  {
    
    $this->preRender();

    // render a view while passing the to-be-rendered data
    echo $this->getView()->render($view . PATH_VIEW_FILE_TYPE, $data_array);
  }
}
```

Now depending on what data you need to build your stuff for `$links` you may or may not need to get a bit more elaborate. Especially given how the URL params are handled in the `Application` class. I really hope you're only doing this as a learning experience because this "framework" you've found isn't really good for much other than learning how you might implement MVC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using it to see how the different parts interact with each other and learn how a MVC style can benefit me and my apps rather than procedural, its more of a learning tool. I understand that PHP can never properly implement the MVC pattern the way its defined, but for now I'm deferentially seeing the benefits of how the code is organised.

Comment: Well its not so much PHP thats the issue, i was more just commenting on the design decisions for this little framework. For example all the routing happens in the `Application` consturctor. In my mind there are at least 2 missing components there - a `Request` model that models an HTTP request, and a `Router` model which handles parsing the parameters from that request in order to execute the controller(s). But happy learning!

Comment: Also i would recommend after you get a bit of a grasp on this you move on to look at how some actual production ready frameworks function. I'd probably check out `Silex`, `Symfony2` or `Zend Framework 2` and `Laravel`.